# why workspace file svn revision is never than repository one?

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I've noticed that my workspace file revision is newer than repository.
Repository revision is valid, local is invalid. I want completely update my workspace to the latest repository state.
On screenshot below "CommonsLogger.h" workspace revision is 65, repository revision is 41.

[image: screenshot]
When I try "replace with - latest from repository" i still have "rev 65" (I expect it to be replaced with the latest repository revision 41).

How can I update my workspace so every single file match latest repository revision?

Comment: Are you perchance looking for the `revert` operation?

Comment: @dhke i'm sorry i do not understand

Comment: `revert` is what the operation of resetting the working copy back to the state of the repository is called. I'm not so sure how you managed to get higher revision numbers in the working copy than in the repo.

Comment: right, i also don't understand how working copy revision might be higher. i think I can't `revert` this change as working copy file is not marked as "changed". it marked as "repository revision 63" which doesn't exist in repository

Comment: You can still `revert` to a particular revision. But there's of course still the cause of the actual problem. Can you check the file's history?